# Group tasks by their priority with Twig and Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, twig

I have 2 entities Task and TaskPriority, relations work.

I want to show all task but order by their priority like that:

Urgent
- Task #1
- Task #3
- Task #8

Todo
- Task #2
- Task #4
- Task #7

I tried that, I know it can't work but it shows what I want to do:

```
{% for priority in tasks.priority %}
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></i>{{ priority.title }}
            </div>

            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    {{ task.title }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

What's the correct way to do that?

**EDIT**

I have already some methods in my TaskRepository:

```
class TaskRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function grabAll()
    {
        $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
            ->leftJoin('t.category', 'c')->addSelect('c')
            ->leftJoin('t.user', 'u')->addSelect('u')
            ->leftJoin('t.project', 'p')->addSelect('p')
            ->orderBy('t.id', 'desc');

        return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
    }

    public function findFilteredItems($users, $categories, $projects, $search)
    {
        $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
            ->leftJoin('t.user', 'u')->addSelect('u')
            ->leftJoin('t.category', 'c')->addSelect('c')
            ->leftJoin('t.project', 'p')->addSelect('p')
            ->orderBy('t.id', 'desc');

        if($users) {
            foreach($users as $id) {
                $queryBuilder->orHaving('u.id = :id')->setParameter('id', $id);
            }
        }

        if($categories) {
            foreach($categories as $id) {
                $queryBuilder->orHaving('c.id = :id')->setParameter('id', $id);
            }
        }

        if($projects) {
            foreach($projects as $id) {
                $queryBuilder->orHaving('p.id = :id')->setParameter('id', $id);
            }
        }

        if($search) {
            $queryBuilder->orWhere('t.title LIKE :search')->setParameter('search', $search);
        }

        return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: The sorting should be done in the controller imho. Create `Repository methods` and return something like this to the template: `return ['urgentTasks' => /*...*/, 'todoTasks' => /*...*/];`.

Comment: I edited my first post with my TaskRepository, I used these methods on multiple pages of my application so I'll have to create two others methods or can I chained? For example create a repository method that group my tasks by group title.

Another noob question how to group task by priority like in your comment with the query builder?